# Default app theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a quick question.

Is there a way, using eclipse, to define a default theme for my app, or do I have to configure each activity and asset to match my desired theme?

If there is a way, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an xml file in res\values. In it create a default layout style like this (you can define other stuff also this is just an example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Use one style for each default theme you want to create. Then in the Widget you want to use this style you enter like this (again just an example):

```
<TextView
style="@style/CodeFont"
android:text="@string/hello" />
```

This TextView will now inherit the settings declared in the style.

Answer (score 4):

Define your `android:theme` in `application` element of your manifest.